# Accessing OkHttpClient Response from multiple threads

Tags: java, okhttp

I would like to use [PipedOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) and [PipedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html)
to stream Response body. I am not quite sure if it is safe in terms of multithreading. The response will be accessed from a different thread.

```java
public Streamer execute() {
    Response response = null;
    try {
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        response = call.execute();
        return stream(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (response != null) response.close();
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Streamer {
    void write(OutputStream out) throws Exception;
}

private static Streamer stream(Response response) throws IOException {

    return out -> {
        // will be executed from a different thread
        try (BufferedSource source = response.body().source();
            Buffer buffer = new Buffer()) {

            BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(out));
            long readBytes;
            long readTotal = 0;
            while ((readBytes = source.read(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                sink.write(buffer, readBytes);
                sink.flush();
                readTotal += readBytes;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

It is safe to pass `Response` object to a different thread and access `body()` and `body().close()` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can pass Response objects to other threads. The only rule is you can’t have multiple threads accessing the response body at the same time.

You might want to look at Pipe in Okio. It's a bit more capable than the java.io pipe thingies.